Value of type {Singleton class} has no member '$showDebugView'
I have a singleton class through which other singleton classes or utils classes are using the properties from. I am using a toggle element from SwiftUI which needs a binding variable. If I use @Published variable from view model or @State variable from the view itself, then everything works fine, but I wish to use the variable from a singleton class as binding variable.
How do I do it?
class AppState {
    static let shared = AppState()
    private init() {}
    
    private(set) var moduleState: ModuleState? = ModuleState.shared
}

class ModuleState {
    static let shared = ModuleState()
    private init() {}
    var moduleState: ModuleState? = ModuleState()
    
    var showDebugView: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Show Debug View",
                   isOn: AppState.shared.moduleState!.$showDebugView.wrappedValue)
                    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: .blue))
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50.0, height: 30.0)
        }
    }
}

With the above code, I am getting "Value of type 'ModuleState' has no member '$showDebugView'" error.
How can I pass showDebugView as binding variable?

Rather than using a singleton, it would be better to inject your AppState into the environment.

Binding means you have a dependency on something, but you seems have no dependency on anything inside ModuleState. So why Binding then?

@timbretimbre - isOn within Toggle needs a Binding property, so I am trying to make it binding. Basically in my app, am not looking for dynamic dependency i.e. If user changes the toggle value, nowhere in the app code is looking for it's dynamic value, but the changed toggle value needs to be stored somewhere so app can use it later.

In SwiftUI the state data should be distributed with many @State in each View not centralised in a shared singleton, that won't work right.

@tech_human not like you provide it there. It's just a bad design.

It is already a Binding. You don't need to use $ to get a Binding from a property wrapper (like you would with @State).
Your code can just be:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Show Debug View",
                   isOn: AppState.shared.moduleState!.showDebugView)
                    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: .blue))
        }
    }
}


Thanks @jnpdx! For my code, I am going with the answer I shared here, but since you answered my question accurately, I am going to choose your solution as the answer. The only problem I faced was since I am setting a constant value to "false" in "var showDebugView: Binding = .constant(false)", app wasn't allowing me to set the switch to on, but that was completely my mistake to set the value as constant in the singleton class.

A good rule of thumb is that having a .constant for a Binding is usually a bad code smell unless it's in a Preview

The only reason I was using Binding in singleton class was because "isOn" within toggle required it. My app is not looking for dynamic change value of the toggle. I found a way to create custom Binding within the Toggle itself.
Sharing the code here if anyone comes looking for it:
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class AppState {
    static let shared = AppState()
    private init() {}
    
    private(set) var moduleState: ModuleState? = ModuleState.shared
}

class ModuleState {
    static let shared = ModuleState()
    private init() {}

    var showDebugView: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Show Debug View",
                   isOn: Binding<Bool> (
                    get: {
                        return AppState.shared.moduleState!.showDebugView
                    },
                    set: {
                        AppState.shared.moduleState!.showDebugView = $0
                        let _ = print("AppState.shared.moduleState!.showDebugView - \(AppState.shared.moduleState!.showDebugView)")
                    }
                 ))
                    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: .blue))
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50.0, height: 30.0)

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

